# MahApps Metro titlebar buttons not styled correctly

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

Win7, VS2012, MahApps.Metro.0.13.1.0, MVVMLight 4.2.30.0

I created the simplest project I could, but the system buttons (Minimize and Close) are not styled correctly.
[image]

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<controls1:MetroWindow
x:Class="MahMetro.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:controls1="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="300" Width="300"
    Title="MVVM Light Application"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize"   WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            <!-- <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" /> -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/IndicatorIcons.xaml"  />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock FontSize="36"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Foreground="Purple"
               Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               TextWrapping="Wrap" />

</Grid>
```

I think I followed the QuickStart correctly -- what have I overlooked?
Thanks --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
```

instead of the commented line you got

```
<!-- <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" /> -->
```

Note the change in spelling for the resource file. You need `Colors.xaml` instead of `Colours.xaml` and it should work fine.

Without `Colors.xaml` you should have seen warnings such as:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='SemiTransparentWhiteBrush'
```

that indicates the `Brush` required by those control's are missing and they are as we can guess defined in `Colors.xaml`. So adding that resource should sort your issue out.